# setting content part hidden at load time while using Jquery UI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am trying to use JQuery UI Tab feature  http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/collapsible.html
but by default the contents are visible to us, even if we havent clicked on any tab.. How do I set it as hidden at page load time

Comment: Ive applied the same plug in... I havent added any extra code..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs( "option", "selected", -1 );
```

For more info see [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected)